# Protractor ConfigParser Error 105 getPage Timeout when trying to print to console

Tags: protractor

In Protractor, I need to run one line of code from the test suite mytest.js
mytest.js file has one line: console log 'my first Protractor test'

I am not loading any webpages. I am only printing to the console.

I have the following latest stable versions:

```
node -v => v8.11.2; npm -v => 6.0.1; protractor --version => 5.3.2
```

`C:\test> protractor conf.js --suite=mytest`

I am getting the following error:

> [15:59:08] E/configParser - Error code: 105 [15:59:08] E/configParser
>   - Error message: failed loading configuration file conf.js [15:59:08] E/configParser - C:\test\conf.js:59 getPageTimeout: 100000, //Timed
>   out waiting for page to load, and alternatively browser.get(address,
>   timeout_in_millis) ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token : at createScript
>   (vm.js:80:10) at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10) at
>   Module._compile (module.js:616:28) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:663:10) at Module.load (module.js:565:32) at tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:505:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3) at
>   Module.require (module.js:596:17) at require
>   (internal/module.js:11:18) at ConfigParser.addFileConfig
>   (C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:135:26)

Comment: You clearly have a syntax error in your protractor config at `C:\test\conf.js`.

Comment: Show the entire content of your  conf.js

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in some line where you have:

```
browser.get(address, timeout_in_millis)
```